# How to create a grid like structure on graph with javascript library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, charts, vtk

I am working on a project to create the reservoir depth in 2D graph from C++ to react. I was able to create the below contour graph with random data with plotly.js.

[image]

But am trying to achieve something like this. Any lead will be helpful.

[image]